# join a record of a text file with all the other records in the same file in mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

this article [xrds:article](http://xrds.acm.org/article.cfm?aid=2331053) in the subsection "An Example of the Tradeoff" describes a way (the first one) that every single record is joined with all the other records of the input file. I wonder how could that be possible in mapreduce without passing the whole input file in only one mapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three major types of joins (there are a few others out there) for MapReduce.

**Reduce Side Join** - For both data sets, you output the "foreign key" as the output key of the mapper. You use something like [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html) to load two data sets at once. In the reducer, data from both data sets is brought together by foreign key, which allows you to do the join logic (like Cartesian product, perhaps) there. This is general purpose and will work for just about every situation.

**Replicated Join** - You push out the smaller data set into the [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html). In each matter, you load the smaller data set from there into memory. As records pass through the mapper, join the data up against the in-memory data set. This is what you suggest in your question. It should be only used when the smaller data set can be stored in memory.

**Composite Join** - This one is a bit niche because it needs to be set up. If two data sets are *sorted* and *partitioned* by the foreign key, then you can do a composite join using [CompositeInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/join/CompositeInputFormat.html). It basically does a merge-like operation that is pretty efficient.

---

Shameless plug for my book [MapReduce Design Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025122.do): there is a whole chapter on joins (chapter 5).

Check out the code examples for the book here: https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/tree/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5

Comment: Thanks for the answer!I didn't know about the existence of DistributedCache class.I will try it and maybe come back for further explanation :)

Comment: some example code on a distributed cache join: https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/blob/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5/ReplicatedJoinDriver.java